# Create shape with curve and non equal width

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create the following shape:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0fiU.png)

```css
   .shape{
       background: #fff;
       box-shadow: 4px 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 300px;
       height: 100%;
       border-radius: 0 20% 0 0;
       transform: skew(160deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Here is a live fiddle to change the code: https://jsfiddle.net/dkL5r7eq

The curve created with `border-radius` needs to be moved a little to the bottom and the space to the left needs to be covered. I tried to use `border-radius` with `transform: rotate()` but didn't work.

I don't want to use SVG because it should be responsive to cover the whole height and width of the parent element so I'm trying to create it with HTML/CSS.

Here is the SVG code:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="728.546" height="1135" viewBox="30 30 728.546 1135">
  <defs>
    <filter id="a" x="0" y="0" width="728.546" height="1135" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feOffset dx="4" input="SourceAlpha" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="10" result="b" />
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.161" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="b" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)" filter="url(#a)">
    <path d="M1679.813-5095.343H1206.271v1075h473.542s180.8-741.334,194.034-823.15C1890.8-4948.331,1679.813-5095.343,1679.813-5095.343Z" transform="translate(-1180.27 5125.34)" fill="#fff" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating an png/jpg image, not a dynamic shape object.

Then set `width`, `height`, `top` and `left` with `position: relative;`